# xrandr config not loading properly at startup from .xprofile

Tags: ubuntu, startup, xrandr

I'm using `xrandr` to rescale the resolution on a netbook (Ubuntu 12.10).  When I run the following command it works fine:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x600 --panning 1280x720 --scale 1.25x1.2
```

However when I put that command into `.xprofile` to load it at startup the screen has a black border in the expanded area rather than the proper output.  I'm using exactly the same command so I'm not sure why it's not working.

Comment: I'd suggest to put `echo "$PATH" >> ~/my-path` into `.xprofile` as well, log out and back in, and post the resulting info from `~/my-path`. My gut feeling is that this is a path issue.

Comment: I don't think it's to do with $PATH, I got

Comment: You got what, a blank line? If so, it's *definitely* a path issue. Do `which xrandr` in a shell and use the full path instead of just the command name in `.xprofile`.

Comment: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Comment: sorry had to switch computers to copy the path output.